# jQuery prepend multiple divs using $(selector).each

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create dash time counter. I used following to create the digit divs

```
$('.dash').each((i, el) => {
    console.log(el);
    el.prepend('<div class="digit"><div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div><div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div></div>');
})
```

I expect it to create something like

```html
<div class="dash days_dash">
  <div class="digit">
    <div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div>
    <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="digit">
    <div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div>
    <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="digit">
    <div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div>
    <div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div>
  </div>
  <h3>Days</h3>
</div>
```

but it simply displays the text as it is on the view. `<div class="digit"><div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div><div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div></div>`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap `el` in `$()` as it is a DOM element, not a jQuery object i.e.

```js
$('.dash').each((i, el) => {
  console.log(el);
  $(el).prepend('<div class="digit"><div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div><div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div></div>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dash">
</div>
<div class="dash">
</div>
```

But you don't actually need an `.each` at all, you can just `prepend` directly:

```js
$('.dash').prepend('<div class="digit"><div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div><div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dash">
</div>
<div class="dash">
</div>
```

Comment: I have multiple elements with dash class

Comment: @mayank1513 I'm not sure what you mean by the reference to `days_dash`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show that as a snippet too.

Comment: ok so there are multiple classes to an element like dash, days_dash then another with dash, hours_dash, like that so I want to run this for all

Answer (score 1):

The [`$('').each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) returns an index and an [`Element`](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element). It is important to note that it does not return a `jQuery` object. This means that when you call `el.prepend` you are not calling the `jQuery` prepend method but the DOM prepend method. The [DOM prepend method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) expects takes either a `Node` object or a `DOMString`. In this case, you are passing a String which gets converted into a `Text Node`.

A simple fix is to change:

```
el.prepend(
```

to this:

```
$(el).prepend(
```

Answer (score 0):

`el.prepend` should be `$(el).prepend`. `el` is a DOM element, so you're calling the native [`prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) method; this treats a string argument as a text node, not HTML.

`$(el)` creates a jQuery object referring to the element. The jQuery [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method parses the HTML.

```js
$('.dash').each((i, el) => {
  console.log(el);
  $(el).prepend('<div class="digit"><div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div><div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div></div>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dash">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you if I understand you question correctly.
In your example, you only have one `<div class="dash"></div>`, so the for loop will only run once. But seems like you want to copy it 3 times.

```
$('.dash').each((i, el) => {
   for(let i=0; i<3;i++) {
        $(el).prepend('<div class="digit"><div class="top" style="display: none;">0</div><div class="bottom" style="display: block;">0</div></div>');
    }
}
```